# Groovy and spring security configurable logout time

Tags: groovy, spring-security, logout

I want to have a property in my domain class for a certain user which could be use to configure the logout time. Is this possible with springSecurity?

I've searched for online example but haven't found anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login credentials are stored in the user's session.  You can set the maximum amount of inactive time per user with something like this after the user has logged in:

```
session.maxInactiveInterval = user.maxInactiveInterval
```

If you want to set the logout time independent of the user's activity, just schedule a timer or job and call `session.invalidate()` at the appropriate time.  Note that this might cut off a user in the middle of a task.

If you're using "remember me" authentication, see the [Spring Security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) for setting the expiry time.

Comment: Didn't knew it was that easy. Thanks